Mongoose Linking Model to Document Error "No document found for query "
I am trying to handle process by creating new order using order model then to proceed with some other action if it failed I will delete back the created order using mongoose,
the problem is after creating the document and try to deleting it giving me always error of
No document found for query "{ _id: new ObjectId('xxxxxxxxxxx') }" on model "Order"

even if I delete it manually from mongodb shell it will give that error direct and crash the application
here is the code :
const orderModel = new Order();    // order model 
   orderModel.create({.....})
       .then((order) => {
        .......
        // try to do something if it fails 
          orderModel.findByIdAndDelete(order._id).then().catch(); // here the error will be triggered or if I try to delete that document anyhow 
})
.catch(error => res.error(error))


Can you please elaborate that what other things you want to do ? Is it other queries which you're doing ?

There is something happens with using mode.create() with a promise , it returns object of created document and somehow there is link with the document in the database if tried to delete it from the database ( mongoshell ) the application will stop with error message ... so in case if i created new document and i need to delete it back the application will crash,, I fix the issue by using insert instead of create but still i need to understand what's happening
